# Trouble installing mysql in EC2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, today I tried installing MySQL in ec2, after a long time I have installed it but in order to log in it is asking root password, which I haven't set. In the terminal, I have noticed the statement saying

"If you have just installed MYSQL, and you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank, so you should just press enter.

I did the same following instruction but I couldn't log in into Mysql. ( I cannot even set the password because it is not in the root)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This might be relevant: [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: B.4.3.2 How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). Or perhaps [Installing MySQL in an EC2 instance. - Chamika Kasun - Medium](https://medium.com/@chamikakasun/installing-mysql-in-an-ec2-instance-55d6a3e19caf) or [How to set root password for aws ec2 with mysql preinstalled?](https://serverfault.com/a/930739/267968). Found them with a simple web search.

Comment: Yeah, I have come across the same.

Comment: but, I am not finding the way how to set the password and log in. Thanks for your kind response, John!

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempts and the error messages that they display.

Comment: definitely. I will try to project my problem in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly consider spinning up a free-tier RDS MySQL instance to test with?